# Automatically make footnote-carrying pages vertically stretchable

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes

My thesis use a page size that is exactly 34 line of text tall.  (10pt text + 33 * 18pt `\baselineskip` = 9in plus 2pt, which looks like 1in margins on an 8.5x11" page).  Some pages contain pretty much solid text, with some footnotes, which makes them have zero vertical stretchability.  The footnotes, though, don't work out to a height that's a multiple of `\baselineskip`.  As a result, LaTeX complains about lots of underfull `\vbox`es.

Is there a way to make the vertical gap between the last line of text on a page, and the top of the footnotes area, stretchable?  I don't want to make my pages use `\raggedbottom` directly, because then the footnotes slide up to the bottom of the text, leaving a (surprise!) ragged bottom to the page.  I want the footnotes to be flush-bottom, and I'd like there to be roughly 1 `\baselineskip` of stretchable space between the text and the footnotes, so that TeX stops complaining :)

My current attempts, in case this helps:  In the thesis class file, it defines `\footskip` as

```
\footskip\z@
```

So I tried playing games like

```
\addtolength{\footskip}{0pt plus 18pt}
\typeout{\the\footskip}
```

But that outputs `0pt` with no `plus 18pt`...  Is `\footskip` not stretchable?  Or is this the wrong page dimension to be tweaking?  Or is there simply a better way to be doing what I want to do?

Comment: `\footskip` is a rigid length, despite its name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit more searching (thanks @egreg for helping me cut off a fruitless avenue of hacking), it turns out there exists a package that does exactly this:

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

Good to know :)

Comment: The name of the parameter to act on is `\skip\footins`; `\footskip` is used in a very different context and has nothing to do with footnotes, but rather with the page footer. Unfortunately the LaTeX developers never felt the necessity to give `\skip\footins` a sensible name; all that's needed would be a simple `\skipdef\footnoteskip=\footins` and `\footnoteskip` would behave like a normal parameter; alas, it's perhaps too late for changing the LaTeX kernel, even though this addition wouldn't do any harm.