# Flexible separation between body and footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I am in the final stage of formatting my thesis and still have to tweak the page layout in several places. LaTeX does generally a good job but some pages come out unsatisfactorily, with widows/orphans, footnotes that continue on the next page, sections that start at the bottom of a page etc. I allow all these in general, but sometimes I would prefer to adjust the text with rewording or with `\looseness` to get a smoother output. Is there an overview that lists some of the possible manual methods in this last stage of polishing?

I have a specific question that concerns the gap/distance/separation between the text body and the footnotes area. I defined this with `\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}` but I would be open for this length to be flexible in cases where a bad layout could be easily prevented. I looked in vain for ways to set it flexible. Is this because it would be bad typographic practice? If yes, why?

I work with `\raggedbottom`, which may be relevant.
See also [Automatically make footnote-carrying pages vertically stretchable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21854/automatically-make-footnote-carrying-pages-vertically-stretchable) and a related discussion in German: https://komascript.de/node/1239

Am I actually just looking for a stretchable length like `1cm plus 0.5cm`? Does LaTeX then choose a length for the best-looking option?

Comment: Have you tried loading the `footmisc` package with the option `bottom`? From section 1.8 of the package's user guide: "[The `bottom`] option forces footnotes to the bottom of the page; this is only noticeably useful in case that `\raggedbottom` is in effect, when LATEX would normally set the footnotes a mere `\skip\footins` distant from the bottom of the text."

Comment: Thank you, I indeed use `\raggedbottom`. But loading `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` does not change my output.

Comment: Sadly, but probably not surprisingly, my psychic divination skills are absolutely rubbish. Since you‘ve provided no actual example of a problem involving the placement of footnotes, I‘m simply not in a position to provide useful advice. My abject apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what You want? (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371138/change-space-between-footnote-line-and-main-text/371139))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the possibility to give a flexible/stretchable length with `plus`. This works also with `\setlength`. If I want the footnotes to sit at the bottom without using the package footmisc (because it changes my footnotes layout) I can use `\renewcommand*\footnoterule{\vfill}`.

Comment: @johnny7: Thanks; I used this to implement `footmisc`'s `bottom` option to avoid the problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422089).